# How to show all the lines I draw by imfreehand

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using a code that allows me to draw freehand on the image. The code is as below:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(I);
for i=1:3
    M = imfreehand(gca,'Closed',0);
    F = false(size(M.createMask));
end
P0 = M.getPosition;
D = round([0; cumsum(sum(abs(diff(P0)),2))]); 
P = interp1(D,P0,D(1):.5:D(end)); 
P = unique(round(P),'rows');
S = sub2ind(size(I),P(:,2),P(:,1));
F(S) = true;
figure;
imshow(F);
imwrite(F,'line.jpg')
```

## Picture 1

[image: pic1]

## Picture 2

[image: pic2]

Using above code, I can draw freehand as I wish on the photo (Picture 1). But in the output figure (Picture 2), it shows only the last figure I've drawn. I want to show all freehand figures that I've drawn. Can anyone suggest me how shall I improve the codes so whatever I draw on pic1 will be shown on pic2. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of the end of your loop (i.e. the `end` syntax) so that you are setting the mask after each iteration. What you are doing instead is capturing all of the strokes, but you are **resetting** the mask that contains the stroke at each iteration. Therefore you only capture the stroke of the last iteration.

You'll need to fix this and once you do, you will also need an external mask variable that **remembers** each stroke as you make it then this is the final mask variable you save in the end.

My edits to your code are seen below delineated in comments:

```
close all;
I = imread('peppers.png');
figure;
imshow(I);

%// New - Create external mask variable that remembers each stroke in the loop
mask = false(size(I,1), size(I,2));

for i=1:3
    M = imfreehand(gca,'Closed',0);
    F = false(size(M.createMask));
    P0 = M.getPosition;
    D = round([0; cumsum(sum(abs(diff(P0)),2))]); 
    P = interp1(D,P0,D(1):.5:D(end)); 
    P = unique(round(P),'rows');
    S = sub2ind(size(I),P(:,2),P(:,1));
    F(S) = true;

    %// Save stroke into external mask
    mask = mask | F;
end %// Move end statement here

%// Show mask then save
figure;
imshow(mask);
imwrite(mask,'line.jpg');
```

The logical OR operation (i.e. `|`) updates the mask with each stroke as you loop through and make new ones.  When I make the above modifications, I now get this image when I tried to replicate your strokes right before it gets saved:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck!